# Generate objective-c code

Tags: objective-c, xml, parsing, generated-code

I need to generate objective-c code based on a number of steps followed in my utility application (Mac OS X app). Something which will trigger "Generate code"...

Has anybody perhaps done something similar to this?

If so, will you be so kind to point in me in the right direction to get started?

I was hoping there might be something like a xml to objective-c parser out there where the xml element and attributes might represent objects and properties in objective-c but can't seem to find anything like that out there.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why don't you just write a script that reads the XML and performs the actions.  That's easy, and there are *zillions* of alternatives.

Comment: Are you actually trying to generate code — that is, produce a text file containing some source code that will need to be compiled — or are you trying to have an XML file specify some actions to be taken in an existing Objective-C program?

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks I guess I tried to over complicated for some reason. I also later realized that the code to be generated can be anything and thus the reason why I couldn't really find a "generic" code generation library. Thanks for the suggestions guys!